# Moving UIImageView in relation to UIScrollView movement

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Under my self.view I have a `UIScrollView` called self.scrollView and under self.scrollView I have two `UIViews` called self.panedView and self.recordView.  My self.panedView has a height of 568 and a Y origin of 0 and my self.recordView has a height of 274 and a Y origin of 568.  My self.scrollView has a content size height that is equal to the height of 842 (height of self.panedView + the height of self.recordView).  I want to add a `UIImageView` called self.iconImageView over self.panedView so that when I scroll, the imageView will move up to a certain position in relation to how much I scroll.  self.iconImageView has a Y position of 184 is only a subclass of self.view.  I was initially moving my self.iconImageView with `UIView animationWithDuration` whenever an up swipe was detected by doing the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.view insertSubview:self.iconImageView aboveSubview:self.panedView];
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    self.iconImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.iconImageView.frame, 0, -85.5);
} completion:nil];
```

How can I replicated this now that I've switch over to a `UIScrollView`?  I'm thinking something like this might work:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

 if(self.iconImageView.center.y >= 184 && self.iconImageView.center.y <=451)
    {
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.iconImageView.center.y + (self.scrollView.contentOffset.y/self.scrollView.contentOffset.y));
    self.iconImageView.center = newCenter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add your UIImageView as a subview of your pannedView? Or just add it directly on top of your pannedView but as a subview of UIScrollView.

Comment: I think including it as a subview of pannedView makes it more tricky.  If its not under scrollView, at least I can take the vertical contentOffSet of scrollView and translate the Y origin of my imageView  to move accordingly by changing the imageView center Y or doing a CGRectOffset.  Its not working as I had hoped.

Comment: So initially I was moving panedView and iconImageView to where I wanted them to be using `UIView animationWithDuration` and `CGRectOffset` when a swipe was detected.  However, now I'm using the scrollView.contentOffset to translate iconImageView to move in relation to the movement of content view.  The problem with this is that iconImageView reaches where its suppose to stop, while panedView still has a long way to go to reach its stopping point.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a). Whenever the scroll view is scrolled(even programatically), you get an event.

Comment: Would I use `scrollViewDidScroll:`?

Comment: Yes, you have to use scrollViewDidScroll. Get contentOffset of scroll view and you know how much it has scrolled.

Comment: I'm able to get the imageView to move along with the scrollView but the movement of the imageView isn't proportionate to the movement of the offset.  The image moves up way too quick in comparison to the movement of the scrollView.  Code is included above.

Comment: Use 

  `if(self.iconImageView.center.y >= 177.5)
  {
    [UIView animateWithDuration....]
  }`

or remove `if(self.iconImageView.center.y >= 177.5)` That should move image as you scroll. Currently its waiting till you reach threshold and suddenly moving after that.

Comment: I edited in my limits for my iconImageView in `scrollViewDidScroll` above. What i noticed is that if i scroll slowly, the iconImageView follows the limits I set.  However, if I scroll really fast, it does not follow the limits i set in `scrollViewDidScroll`

Comment: I do not see any thing in code that decides fast/slow animation. If you are unsure how its working , add debug code (like NSLog) and observer how the coordinates are changing. Also I see your move to one position when `y >= 184` but you do not move it back when `y < 184`

Comment: Should I be implementing code that decides fast/slow animation?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Experiment a bit wit Logs, if else, break points. You'll figure out what is wrong.